# error: request for member 'multitaskingSupported' in something not a structure or union

Tags: iphone, ios4

I tried to run this code on iPhone Simulator 4.0 and get that error

```
//#ifdef __IPHONE_4_0
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)] && device.multitaskingSupported)
    {


    }
//#endif
```

Does anyone have worked on the Multitasking with Simulator before ? Please help me.

Many Thanks

Tung Do

Comment: @KennyTM: error: request for member ‘multitaskingSupported’ in something not a structure or union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you compiling for the 4.0 SDK? Before the 4.0 SDK, the property `multitaskingSupported` is not defined, so the compiler will fail. Try

```
if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)] &&
    [device isMultitaskingSupported]) {
      ...
}
```

instead.

Comment: I found the problem. need to change Base SDK to iPhone 4.0 in Target properties instead of in Project properties.